# Prove or disprove a statement regarding sets

Tags: finite-groups, infinite-groups

Blessings I need help with proving or disproving a group of statements regarding sets / groups

A,B are groups. It is said that B = A - {1}. prove or disprove the following claims:

A. if A has the same cardinality as B then A is infinite.

B. if A!=B and if A has cardinality to B then A is infinite.

C. if A - {2} has cardinality to B then A is infinite.

Things i've already tried are

A. incorrect. counter proof : `B = {} A = {} \ {1}, an empty set isn't infinite.`

B.

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5,...} = {n|nEN} 
B = {2,3,4,5,6,...} = {n|NEN} 
B = A \ {1}
B != A
```

C. Wasn't able to anwser yet.

Comment: I am not sure the question makes sense. If $A$ and $B$ are groups, and assuming $1 \in A$ is the identity, then do you mean $B = A \backslash \{1\}$ to mean $B = A - \{1\}$, or to mean $B$ is the quotient group $A / \{1\}$? In the first case, $B$ would *not* be a group. In the second case, clearly $B \cong A$. If you meant to replace the word "group" with the word "set", the questions make sense, but this is why you must be exceedingly careful with wording.

Comment: You are correct. B = A - {1}. I've fixed the post aswell.. guess it's displayed slightly differently in my country.

Comment: You are still calling $A$ and $B$ "groups" when apparently what you mean is just "set". "Group" has a specific meaning in mathematics, and it is different from "set'. Removing a single element from a *group* is not going to be another *group* - ever.  As for your questions - for (A) you are correct about the *sets*. If $1\notin A$, then $A\setminus \{1\} = A$, regardless of the size of $A$. But for (B), all you done is list an example, meeting conditions. It shows it is *possible* for $A$ to be infinite. It does not show that $A$ has to be infinite, which is the question. (C) is like (A).